# Grails not translating classpath in Config.groovy

Tags: grails

In  grails-app/conf/config.groovy
I have

```
    grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:confDev1.groovy",
       "file:${userHome}/confDev2.groovy"]
```

both file exists.
in debugging when i evaluate

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.config.locations
```

I get

```
"classpath:confDev1.groovy",
"file:adminLaptop/confDev2.groovy"
```

grails is not getting the classpath file. Seems like he is not translating classpath, just keeoing it as String.

the second file is correctly added.

how to put config files in classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

```
grails.config.locations = [ 
    "classpath:confDev1.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/confDev2.groovy"
]
```

Putting above code in grails project's Config.groovy means that there are two configuration files **confDev1.groovy** and **confDev2.groovy**. One is present in the application's classpath, while another is on file system path.

It doesn't mean that grails will look into your whole file system and then will put **confDev1.groovy** to application's classpath.

To externalize the config, a good approach would be, put your external config file in the base directory of your project. Copy this file to classpath whenever run app or war creation event triggers.

To copy a file from base directory to class path on run-app or war-creation event, you can create a custom script.

**Hooking into Grails Events**

As you are specifying that the configurations will be loaded from the classpath or system path, you need to be hooking into the Grails events to make sure that the file is in the classpath. Create a file under **scripts/_Events.groovy** and paste the code given below.

```
//Hook into war creation event
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
  ant.copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes") {
    fileset(file: "${basedir}/confDev2.groovy")
  }
}

//Hook into run-app event
eventRunAppStart = {
  ant.copy(todir:"${basedir}/target/classes") {
    fileset(file: "${basedir}/confDev2.groovy")
  }
}
```